# Autoscaling an image after using the Matrix.postRotate() method

Tags: java, android, image, matrix, scale

I used the `Matrix.postRotate()` method to rotate my image but now it no longer autoscales to fit the parent `LinearLayout`.  Here's the relevant code...

```
private ImageView rotateimage(ImageView dotimage) {

Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
dotimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix.postRotate((float) 90, 374, 374);
dotimage.setImageMatrix(matrix);

return dotimage;}
```

and here is my xml for the layout and `ImageView`...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="550dp"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dotdescription"
        android:src="@drawable/dots1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have fixed the scaling using the `Matrix.postScale()` method but I was really just curious why the autoscale no longer works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, autoscale doesn't work because you've explicitly changed it to `ScaleType.MATRIX` -- and that means all transformations should be handled by your matrix.